# How can non-CG shader code in Unity be included?

Tags: unity, shaders

In Unity shaders, #include, #define, and other preprocessor commands seem to not be able to be used outside the CGPROGRAM section of the shader. Since these are required for compiling multiple shader variants, and a large portion of the shader is non CG, this would be incredibly useful to reduce shader duplication. Do these commands exist outside CG?

Comment: check [this link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-BuiltinMacros.html)